# How can I find all dangling pointers in a code?

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

I want to find the dangling pointers in code (which got created as a result of shallow copying). Consider the below example..

```
int *a = new int(1);
int *b = a;
int *c = b;
delete a;
```

Now I want to find all such pointers like b and c in code. How can I do that?
I tried using valgrind but it only shows the error when I actually try to read it, but here I'm not reading these variables.

Comment: There is a solution for the general problem already: smart pointers. Never use raw owning pointers

Comment: Surely finding all such pointers for a given program is an undecidable problem. Best you can do is listen to the advice and eliminate all `new` calls.

Comment: No, they do not point to a "random location" after deleting `a`.  They have the same value you gave them to begin with.  There is nothing intrinsically magical about pointers.  It's not clear what you believe is happening or what you expect should be done about it.

Comment: Usually pointers which are dangling but never used again aren't a concern, so why do you want this? If the trouble is that they're still accessible from some public interface, perhaps what would really help would be a more complete test of that interface which could expose issues after "cleanup"?